# what is nn.index mean in KNN output

Tags: r, classification

I am getting `attr(, "nn.index")` as part of my KNN output in R. What is meant by that and how is this value getting calculated?

```
knn.pred <- knn(tdm.stack.nl_train, tdm.stack.nl_Test, tdm.cand_train)
print(knn.pred)

> knn.pred


[1] Silent      Silent      Silent      Silent      Silent      Silent      Silent     
 [8] Silent      Silent      Silent    


attr(,"nn.index")


      [,1]
[1,]  292  
[2,]  292  
[3,]  343  
[4,]  444  
[5,]  250  
[6,]  445  
[7,]  270  
[8,]  228  
[9,]  302  
[10,]  355
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the `fnn` package.

`attr` is a list of attributes which can be used for both `nn.index` and `nn.dist`. In this case, you are using `index`.

So, index returns an n x k matrix for the nearest neighbor indice.

And the definition of the nearest neighbor index is:

> The nearest neighbor index is expressed as the ratio of the observed
>   distance divided by the expected distance.

[Definition reference](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net/shared/geoprocessing/spatial_statistics_tools/average_nearest_neighbor_spatial_statistics_.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there anyway to know what their actual value of observed distance and expected distances are? I am using KNN algorithm for a classification problem in  text mining project and i want to know find the keywords influencing  the classification. It wil be helpful if you can let me know how to retrive the absolute values of these distances. Thank you.

Comment: For that, you use `nn.dist` instead of `nn.index `.  However, the documentation of the `fnn` package would help you understand better  (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/FNN.pdf)